# L1 loss different scale for small or large boxes [object detection]

Tags: computer-vision

In this paper[1] there is a section where it is mentioned that “The most commonly used L1 loss will have different scales for small and large objects even if their relative errors are similar”.

I don’t understand this statement. Can anybody explain?

[1]: [End-to-End Object Detection with Transformers](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.12872)

Comment: We expect references to fulfill the minimal scholarly requirements and be as robust over time as possible. Please take some time to improve your post in this regard. We have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1201/). This will hopefully help others with a similar question about the same paper find this page via search. Thank you!